# Replacing parts of a string simultaneously

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to make an "encrypter" in python that changes everything in a string by a "key" file.

Code:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
alphabet = list(alphabet)
cryptkey = open("cryptkey", "r")
key = cryptkey.read(36)

text = list(key)
tocrypt = open("tocrypt.txt", "r")    
tocryptvar = tocrypt.read()
tocryptvar = tocryptvar.lower()
################################################    Replacement
tocryptvar = tocryptvar.replace("a", key[0]).replace("b", key[1]).replace("c", key[2]) #etc
```

The key is just the alphabet and the numbers shuffled and put in a file.
So, my problem is that when say, A gets replaced to say B its all good but then it changes B to say, G, then A has become G. And thats it.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input, your wrong output and the output you needed it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import string as str_module

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
key = None
with open("cryptkey", "r") as f:
    key = f.read(36)

tocryptvar = None
with open("tocrypt.txt", "r") as f:
    tocryptvar = f.read().lower()

trans_table = str_module.maketrans(alphabet, key)

tocryptvar = tocryptvar.translate(trans_table)
```

`alphabet` is a string of characters to be translated using the key, `key` is a string of characters that corresponding characters from `alphabet` will be translated into. `string.maketrans()` creates a translation string from `alphabet` to `key`, and `tocryptvar.translate(trans_table)` translates the string using the translation table (characters not in the `alphabet` remain the same).

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to set your key as a dictionary, and then replace the plain text by looping through it:

```
key = {}
key['a'] = '4' # here '4' is your replacement

plain = 'hello there'
cryptext = ''.join(key.get(i, i) for i in plain)
```

Here is a quick way to test it out

```
import string
import random

letters = list(string.ascii_letters+string.digits)
random.shuffle(letters)

# This creates a random key for each letter, a simple
# substitution
key = {v:letters[i] for i,v in enumerate(string.ascii_letters+string.digits)}

plain_string = 'hello world'
cryptext = ''.join(key.get(i,i) for i in plain_string)
```

Output from that is something like `'fLXXc ocMXg'`

By the way, `string.ascii_letters` is the entire alphabet (including capital letters) and `string.digits` are the numbers 0 through 9

Comment: I might use `dict(zip(..))` rather than enumerating, but this is how I'd do it too.  (It's also more generalizable than `translate`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through each character of the string and individually replace them with their substitution.

Comment: Code example? I'm very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
key = list(open("cryptkey", "r").read(36))
mapping=dict(zip(alphabet,key))

tocryptvar = open("tocrypt.txt", "r").read().lower()
cryptedval=''.join([mapping[k] for k in tocryptvar])
```